# Validate form data using API and display errors under the corresponding field in Flutter

Tags: flutter, forms, api, dart, validation

I have a login page and I need to validate the user's email and password. I can check password length, strongness, etc, and verify that the typed email is in a correct email format using the `validator` method of `TextFormField`. However, this kind of checking is not sufficient since I still need to query the server (via API) to see if the email exists in the database and if the credentials are right. So, if the credentials are not right, how can I display errors under the `TextFormField` like they were a result of a validation coming from the `validator` method?
I want something like this:

[image: How I would want the validation to look]

Otherwise, the error will be displayed as a message via a snack bar, like this:

[image: Display API validation with a snack bar]

This might be a good solution for just a field, but in my app I have several forms with lots of fields that need API validation, so the snack bar method will not be appropriate.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // Email field
          TextFormField(
            controller: emailController,
            validator: (String? value) {
              if (value != null && value.isValidEmail) return null;
              return 'Invalid email.';
            },
          ),
          // Password field
          TextFormField(
            controller: passwordController,
            validator: (String? value) {
              if (value != null && value.length >= 8) return null;
              return 'Invalid email.';
            },
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Submit'),
            onPressed: () async {
              try {
                // Perform validation using the API.
                // If the form data is invalid, an exception will be thrown.
                // formData is retrieved from the TextFormField controllers.
                await apiValidationCall(formData);

                // Login ended successfully, go to the homepage.
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');

              } catch (error) {
                // Display errors without a snack bar.
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51012721/15868701

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I added some string in the text of the controllers when the error occurs. Here is the code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // Email field
          TextFormField(
            controller: emailController,
            validator: (String? value) {
              if (value.endsWith("not-registered")) {
                return 'This email is not registered.';
              }
              if (value != null && value.isValidEmail) return null;
              return 'Invalid email.';
            },
          ),
          // Password field
          TextFormField(
            controller: passwordController,
            validator: (String? value) {
              if (value.endsWith("wrong-password")) {
                return 'Wrong password.';
              }
              if (value != null && value.length >= 8) return null;
              return 'Invalid email.';
            },
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Submit'),
            onPressed: () async {
              try {
                // Perform validation using the API.
                // If the form data is invalid, an exception will be thrown.
                // fomData is retrieved from the TextFormField controllers.
                await apiValidationCall(formData);

                // Login ended successfully, go to the homepage.
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');

              } catch (error) {
                // Display errors without a snack bar.
                //Catch the error of invalid email
                var realEmail  = '';
                var realPassword  = '';
                if(error == 'invalid email'){
                  realEmail = emailController.text;
                  emailController.text = emailController.text + "not-registered";
                  _formKey.currentState.validate();
                  emailController.text = realEmail;
                }

                //Catch the error of wrong password
                if(error == 'invalid email'){
                  realPassword = passwordController.text;
                  passwordController.text =
                      "wrong-password" + passwordController.text ;
                  _formKey.currentState.validate();
                  passwordController.text = realPassword;
                }
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```